# select rows in R with some value

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a dataset like:

```
df
id1                             id2
Liquor - Alcohol/Illegal sale    23
Arson                            21
Alcohol/Sale without license     20
Burglary                         34
```

Is there some way to replace all Alcohol related rows (here, rows 1 and 3) with just a single string "Alcohol"?
For eg:

```
df
id1                             id2
Alcohol                          23
Arson                            21
Alcohol                          20
Burglary                         34
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use grep.

```
rows_with_alcohol <- grep("Alcohol", df$id1)
df[rows_with_alcohol, "id1"] <- "Alcohol"
```